# Android web server annotations

Tags: android, spring, rest, server

We are looking to add a restful web server to our embedded android application (Not an app, an appliance running Android). Is it possible to use Spring or another java web server annotation framework in an android app?

Answer (score 0):

Qoute "MiniWeb is a Http server library written in Java targeted for embedded projects. MiniWeb's goals are to be small and lightweight as possible while providing simple and easy to use API. MiniWeb uses the very mature and robust Apache HttpComponents at its core. MiniWeb only supports what is necessary to get an embedded web project up and running quickly (no servlets)."
https://github.com/dinocore1/MiniWeb

Good luck